How to have access to the predefined variables for merge request pipelines in GitLab?
I'm trying to have access to these predefined variables for merge requests pipelines in GitLab, but apparently my pipeline is set up as basic pipelines, thus having access only to these variables. I basically need only the CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID var. What do I need to configure (in terms of .gitlab-ci.yml, project, etc) in order to "convert" a basic pipeline into a merge request pipeline in GitLab?

You can't "convert" a pipeline. Gitlab predefined variables are created based on the type of pipeline that ran. Merge request pipelines (that run after committing to a source branch that has an open MR, or opening a new MR) will contain a CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID var as well as other unique MR variables like for source and target branch names.
If you could share why you have to use the CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID it might help solving your original problem.

CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID is available as a predefined CI when you create a Merge request. It are not available in Branch and Tags pipelines. On the other hand, for example CI_COMMIT_BRANCH is not available as a predefined CI variable during a merge request.
For example in the following one, I am running a job only if a merge request has been created ($CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event") and the target of the merge request is the main branch of repository:
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Test"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: always
    - when: never

